# A problem on inequality and number theory

Tags: inequality, radicals, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$;

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{1-x_ix_{i+1}}\ge\sqrt{n(n-1)}\tag{1}$$

where $,  x_1= x_{n+1}, \displaystyle \quad\forall x_i\in\mathbb{R} \text{ and }\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=1 $

Is it possible to find all the positive integer numbers $n$ which satisfy $(1)$ ?

Comment: I cannot make head or tails of this. Obviously neither (1) nor (2) holds for **all** $x_i\in\Bbb{R}$, which is what you are saying. Are you asking for a list of integers $n$ such that both (1) and (2) hold for **some** choice of $x_i$s?? Anyway, this ain't number theory. Were you just throwing tags at random without understanding what they mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you for correcting me!

Comment: I think, but the asker will have to clarify, that we want to find all natural numbers $n$ such that (2) holds whenever (1) does.

Comment: That's another possibility, @Dylan. Possibly a more interesting one:-) We need to wait for the asker to edit the question to make it clear what they mean.

Comment: Yes, (1) looks more like a nonlinear constraint to the nonlinear optimization like problem (2).

Comment: I would vote to close as *unclear what you are asking*, but because my vote is instantly binding that is not kosher.

Comment: I hope it is now clear after editing. thanks for comments and suggestions!

Comment: It's still not entirely clear if you want to find all $n$ such that we *can* choose the $x_i$'s so that the inequality holds, or if you want to find all $n$ such that *no matter how we choose* the $x_i$'s, the inequality always holds as long as $\sum x_i^2 = 1$. (I think that the second version is the intended one, because the answer for the first version is "all $n$".)

Comment: OK. Updated. thank you for making it clearer.

Comment: @user6043040 I have a proof for $n=3$ and for $n=4$.

Comment: It was said that, for $n>20$ that is no such solution, and for $n\le 5$ the proof would be not so difficult. Post the answers here, I can give you at least my upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proof for $n=4$.

Id est, for $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$ we need to prove that:
$$\sqrt{1-ab}+\sqrt{1-bc}+\sqrt{1-cd}+\sqrt{1-da}\geq2\sqrt3$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}(1-ab)+2\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{(1-ab)(1-bc)}+2\sqrt{(1-ab)(1-cd)}+2\sqrt{(1-bc)(1-da)}\geq12$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{(1-ab)(1-bc)}+\sqrt{(1-ab)(1-cd)}+\sqrt{(1-bc)(1-da)}\geq4+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}ab$$
Now by C-S we obtain
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{(1-ab)(1-bc)}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2+c^2+d^2)(b^2-bc+c^2+a^2+d^2)}=$$
$$=\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\left(\left(b-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}a^2+\frac{3}{4}c^2+\frac{1}{4}c^2+d^2\right)\left(\left(b-\frac{c}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}a^2+\frac{3}{4}c^2+\frac{1}{4}a^2+d^2\right)}\geq$$
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\left(b-\frac{a}{2}\right)\left(b-\frac{c}{2}\right)+\frac{3}{4}a^2+\frac{3}{4}c^2+\frac{1}{4}ac+d^2\right)=$$
$$=\frac{7}{2}-ab-bc-cd-da+ac+bd$$
In another hand, by C-S again we obtain
$$\sqrt{(1-ab)(1-cd)}=\sqrt{(a^2-ab+b^2+c^2+d^2)(c^2-cd+d^2+a^2+b^2)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\left(\frac{(a-b)^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}c^2+\frac{1}{2}d^2\right)\left(\frac{(c-d)^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{1}{2}b^2\right)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(a-b)(d-c)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(ad+bc)=\frac{1}{2}+ad+bc-\frac{1}{2}(ac+bd)$$
similarly we'll obtain
$$\sqrt{(1-ad)(1-bc)}\geq\frac{1}{2}+ab+cd-\frac{1}{2}(ac+bd)$$
Thus, 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{(1-ab)(1-bc)}+\sqrt{(1-ab)(1-cd)}+\sqrt{(1-bc)(1-da)}\geq\frac{9}{2}$$
and it remains to prove that
$$\frac{9}{2}\geq4+\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{cyc}ab$$ or
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\geq ab+bc+cd+da$$ or
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-d)^2+(d-a)^2\geq0$$
Done!

Comment: This is already the best results so far so I accept this answer though there is only result for $n=4$. Since this post seems unclear, I created another here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985923/inequality-problems-in-different-cases-of-n-difficult