# Inequality problems in different cases of $n$ [Difficult]

Tags: inequality

For $5\le n\le 19$, $a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_n\ge 0$ and $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k^2=1$, prove that:

$$\sqrt{1-a_1a_2}+\sqrt{1-a_2a_3}+\sqrt{1-a_3a_4}+\cdots+\sqrt{1-a_na_1}\ge\sqrt{n(n-1)}$$

**Update**（counterexamples to $n$ beyond the scope）

I originally expected that the global minimum of `lhs` is exactly `rhs`. However, I check by numerical optimization in Mathematica by `Differential Evolution` algorithm that, for $n>20$, smaller than `rhs` local minimizer can be numerically achieved. The codes are:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
n=22;
Print["sqrt of n(n-1):"]
Sqrt[n(n-1)]//N[#,40]&
var=Table[Subscript[a,k],{k,n}];
Print["When all variables are equal:"]
{Sqrt[1-Subscript[a,1] Subscript[a,n]]+Sum[Sqrt[1-Subscript[a,k] Subscript[a,k+1]],{k,n-1}]}/.Thread[var->1/Sqrt[n]]//N[#,40]&
Print["Random seed:"]
rseeds=RandomInteger[99]
Print["NMinimize Solution"]
sol=NMinimize[{Sqrt[1-Subscript[a,1] Subscript[a,n]]+Sum[Sqrt[1-Subscript[a,k] Subscript[a,k+1]],{k,n-1}]}~Join~Thread[1>=var>=0]~Join~{Total@(var^2)==1},var,Method->{"DifferentialEvolution","RandomSeed"->rseeds},WorkingPrecision->50]
{Sqrt[1-Subscript[a,1] Subscript[a,n]]+Sum[Sqrt[1-Subscript[a,k] Subscript[a,k+1]],{k,n-1}]}/.Last@sol
```

Results:

> sqrt of n(n-1):
>
> 21.49418526020467703924401057548171299596
>
> When all variables are equal:
>
> 21.49418526020467703924401057548171299596
>
> Random seed:
>
> 97
>
> NMinimize Solution
>
> {21.493958088361718757508756191304024461882549266188, $$\begin{array}{rl}
> a_1\to&0.27551074101367342222780049146552671553141115720781\\
> a_2\to&0.24122101942591859516896035008786114084222080634210\\
> a_3\to&0.20686031925778095999625358660583743030950178927919\\
> a_4\to&0.17577853782894785232564071925930202897837797620107\\
> a_5\to&0.14967776232864740441800976481499462604156652376732\\
> a_6\to&0.12919237259005274526751896356388549836657598687909\\
> a_7\to&0.11439952750687089613978518627483806246516035842270\\
> a_8\to&0.10507233393317968236379206706172547805340715644522\\
> a_9\to&0.10101354732229610358754955223851289466594306555616\\
> a_{10}\to&0.10215969656778251068580715934518992632384781887479\\
> a_{11}\to&0.10851219137727185962358704265924136455115927676940\\
> a_{12}\to&0.12020966542805764693753571335235270582328771351713\\
> a_{13}\to&0.13749524018489170480661186121587722167726253796253\\
> a_{14}\to&0.16047577556457054303088930254045653682972975693984\\
> a_{15}\to&0.18889853876426131135197586875434934304601287018713\\
> a_{16}\to&0.22171666754106704676947535912078689424836159977455\\
> a_{17}\to&0.25655322766782152064878861383995289461345663919666\\
> a_{18}\to&0.28932738110835094055030451354655289547312222971662\\
> a_{19}\to&0.31452382324755012672904620877170420894722451824547\\
> a_{20}\to&0.32680622312811119929265771484173921350691759958035\\
> a_{21}\to&0.32326625988701552021297482437342530033165491570368\\
> a_{22}\to&0.30475064029155834486956174539864169866495135183824
> \end{array}$$}

Comment: Is it given any counterexample for $n = 20$?

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: The inequality does not hold for $n\ge 20$. The idea of a proof is to construct $x_1, \ x_2, \ \cdots, \ x_n$ which are functions of a parameter $t$ and when $t=0$ it holds that $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then let $f(t) = LHS - RHS$ (so $f(0)=0$) and prove that $f'(0) = 0$ and $f''(0) < 0$.